# How to export Fields to CSV in OPENEDGE

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Good day

I have a 2 parts problem. currently i have a list of tables and its data needs to be exported to csv. My code is here:

```
def temp table tt-table
field f1 as int
field f2 as char
field . . . .

output to value(session:temp-directory + "temp.csv").

put f1 at 1
"," f2. . .       

 output close.
```

is there a way to do this automatically or to shorten this code? there are 30-40 fields each table average and 5 tables needs to be exported.

Second part:

if i imported them back to our system, is it possible to dynamically create variables based on the number of fields and their corresponding variable types?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `IMPORT` and `EXPORT` statements. To export the temp table to a CSV file, use this code:

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE(SESSION:TEMP-DIRECTORY + "temp.csv").

FOR EACH tt-table NO-LOCK:
    EXPORT tt-table.      
END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

I don't know of a way to dynamically build a temp table from the file. But to import the file into the same table, do this:

```
INPUT FROM VALUE(SESSION:TEMP-DIRECTORY + "temp.csv").

REPEAT:
    CREATE tt-table.
    IMPORT tt-table.
END.

INPUT CLOSE.
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. i tried the export and it worked like a charm. but when i opened it by notepad, there is no delimiter. Can i assign it with delimiter "," ? without quotes. thanks

Comment: thanks. i got the export part and added delimiter to it,. will try import thanks.

Comment: @noob `EXPORT DELIMITER "," tt-table` will do that.

Comment: thanks. i got that earlier. i have another question though but not related to this one. thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. when I export, there is an additional next line after the last row of data and it creates an empty row of data when i import.  how do i remove it without editing the exported file? my temp fix for this was to add a DELETE tt-table after import but this is very risky. any suggestions?

Comment: It's probably creating one last tt-table when it hits the end of the file. You can check a key field to make sure it has a valid value, and if not, delete the record. That's safer than just a delete at the end, and it can also catch any bad data that might be in the CSV file.